# Handling button that grabs value from an input

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is, to create a button that will change size of specific text, The value of the new size is a input type, A user will fill the input with his new size  and once he clicks the button, it'll apply the new size he just entered ( Don't worry about undefined inputs )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 id="imp">First Text</h2>

<p id="demo">Second text.</p>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo')">Click Me to change the second text size to</button> 

<input type="input" value="Input your size"> PX



<br></br>


<button type="button" onclick = "document.getElementById('imp')"> Click me to change the first text size to  </button>

<input type="input" value="Input your size"> PX



</body>
<script>




</script>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<button type="button" onclick = "display()"> Click me to change the first text size</button>

<script>
 function display() {
            document.getElementById("myID").style.fontFamily = "verdana,sans-serif";
            document.getElementById("myID").style.fontSize = "smaller";
         }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Java Script**

```
function changeFontSize(id, idOfInput) {
   var size = document.getElementById(idOfInput).value;
   document.getElementById(id).style.fontSize= size + "px";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 id="imp">First Text</h2>

<p id="demo">Second text.</p>


<button type="button" onclick="changeFontSize('demo', 'demoText');">Click Me to change the second text size to</button>

<input type="text" value="Input your size" id="demoText"> PX

<br></br>

<button type="button" onclick="changeFontSize('imp', 'impText');"> Click me to change the first text size to  </button>

<input type="text" value="Input your size" id="impText"> PX
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle it. I've created a function in the script tag that can be called on both click events. It accepts the text id and the input id as parameters. The value of the input is set to a variable and I used set attribute to apply inline styling to the text element. I also set your initial input value to nothing and instead displayed the text as a placeholder so the user doesn't have to select all before entering their input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 id="imp">First Text</h2>

<p id="demo">Second text.</p>


<button type="button" onclick="setTextSize('demo', 'firstInput')">Click Me to change the second text size to</button> 

<input id="firstInput" type="input" value="" placeholder="Input your size"> PX



<br></br>

<button type="button" onclick ="setTextSize('imp', 'secondInput')"> Click me to change the first text size to  </button>

<input id="secondInput" type="input" value="" placeholder="Input your size"> PX



</body>
<script>
function setTextSize(elementId, inputId) {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    const textElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
    textElement.setAttribute("style", `font-size: ${inputValue}px;`);
};
</script>

</html>
```